# Image not show in Xamarin Forms Android Project

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Good morning colleagues, I am having problems with the images via URI in the Xamarin Forms Android project, the images I can see in the emulator but when testing on physical devices, they are not shown, searching on the internet I found that the HttpClient implementation should be changed, I already did it, I have AndroidClientHandler and TLS 1.2+ but still the physical device does not show the image.

Create a project from 0 just to try, the only thing I have in this is an image, but it gives me the same result, in the emulator it shows, in the device no.`

In iOS everything works normal.

Can You help me?

Comment: Do the images load in the device's browser? Also review `logcat` output for any errors/warning.

Comment: Yes, the image load in the device browser.

Comment: 1) Did you provide Internet permissions in the Android manifest? 2) Are you sure the url starts with "https://"? 3) Do you face the same problem with a tiny image size? 4) Do you face the same problem with a different image format-PNG vs JPG?

Comment: [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please

Comment: Yes, the android manifest have internet permission, I've try with http and https url, not matter the size of the image, I've try with jpg, png, gif and tiff.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t why the image load doesn´t works in my computer, y have a MacBook Pro, with Catalina and bootcamp with Windows 10 1903, in both with the last update of Visual Studio and Android SDK; in both i unistall VS and reinstall it both doesnt work the image load.

I tried in a parent computer, an 7 years old HP with Windows 10 1903, i intall VS and my app woks normally, with the same configuration i can load the image by URL; this was my solution.

Answer (score -1):

you could try this,it works for me:

right click you android project -> **Properties** -> **Android Options** -> **Advanced** ->select **Android** in **HttpClient implementation** and select **Native TLS 1.2+** in **SSL/TSL implementation**

sometime need add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in your `<application>` of **AndroidManifest**.xml

```
<application android:label="App18.Android" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"></application>
```